# Conceptual (Basic) Questions about Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

I'm really new to C programming, and for 1 of our homework assignment we've basically had to recover a jpg images from a memory card. My code is this:

```
#include <cs50.h>       
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// typedef uint8_t BYTE; 
// #define BUFFER_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //opens the memory card for reading
    FILE* mem = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (mem == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char buffer[512];
    FILE* img = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (fread(&buffer, 512,1,mem) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xe0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (found == 1)
                fclose(img);
            else
                found = 1;


        char filename[8];
        sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
        img = fopen(filename, "a");
        count++;
        }

        if (found ==1)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer,512,1,img);
        }
    }

    fclose(mem);
    fclose(img);
    return 0;
}
```

// #1 why does it not matter if its &buffer and not buffer
// #2 how does appending to an array work, conceptually

This works, but I was just wondering:

1. When I use an unsigned char buffer[512], as I did in this case, it works, but when I try it with a char buffer[512], it breaks due to segmentation fault, and so I was just wondering what' the difference between a char and an unsigned char array in terms of memory?
2. I'm a little confused conceptually about why this would work, because I've always thought that arrays have a fixed size and yet in this case:

   `char filename[8];
   sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
   img = fopen(filename, "a");
   count++;`

I'm not exactly sure what's happening because i'm opening an array onto a block of memory and then... to that array?

A portion of the code was given to us in a video walkthrough for the homework, and now that I've finished it I'm just a little confused by some of the concepts - appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: ¿What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 why does it not matter if its &buffer and not buffer // #2 how does appending to an array work, conceptually

Okay, here we go: Arrays in C are a rather confusing thing conceptually in a lot of ways. They share some characteristics with primitive types such as `char` and `int`, in that they're essentially values, they're allocated on the stack, and they're automatically deallocated when they go out of scope, so you don't have to worry about freeing them. However, they share their *interface* with pointers; the syntax, using square brackets, to access the first, second, third, etc. element of an array is the same as the syntax to access the first, second, third, etc. element of a buffer in the heap to which you have a pointer. This isn't necessarily terribly confusing in and of itself; it's not that unreasonable for there to be two distinct types that share a similar interface, if that interface makes sense in both cases.

However: Arrays have a little piece of "magic" to them; if you assign an array to anything—whether it's a variable, or an argument you're passing to a function—it will automatically be converted into a pointer to the array's first element.

```
char foo[512];   // an array of size 512
char *bar = foo; // a *pointer* to the first element in the array
```

This automatic conversion is somewhat surprising in a "close-to-the-metal" language like C that usually has you spell out exactly what you're going to do; additionally, the fact that pointers and arrays are so interchangeable makes it easy to assume that arrays actually *are* pointers, and that pointers actually *are* arrays. However, they're not the same, and one noticeable difference is the answer to the question you asked here: why does your call to `fread` work no matter whether you pass `buffer` or `&buffer`? Well, suppose you have the following variables:

```
int foo;
char bar[8];
int baz;
```

Assuming a machine in which the size of `int` is 4, you can imagine these laid out in memory something like this:

```
-------------------------------------
||f¦o¦o¦ ||b¦a¦r¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ||b¦a¦z¦ ||
||1¦2¦3¦4||1¦2¦3¦4¦5¦6¦7¦8||1¦2¦3¦4||
-------------------------------------
```

Looking at this visual abstraction, you can see something; the address where `bar` sits is (obviously) the same address where its first element, `b` lies, and therefore, when you pass `bar` to something taking a `char *` and it's converted to a pointer to its first element, *that's the same address as the address of the array itself.* This is why, if you log both an array and the address of the array, you get the same value both times:

```
char foo[512];
printf("%p %p\n", (void *)foo, (void *)&foo); // these will both log the same address
```

By contrast, if `foo` is a *pointer* rather than an array (that is to say, it's typed as `char *` rather than `char []`), you will actually get *different* values for `foo` and `&foo`, and passing `&foo` to a function like `fread` will not work properly. This is because unlike an array, a pointer does not represent the data itself, but rather can be thought of as a signpost directing you towards data which is stored in some other location, and therefore, its address is *not* the address of the data.

The reason this magic exists is basically for convenience, so that you can use an array as if it were a pointer. However, this creates new pitfalls for you to have to watch out for. For example, you can't return an array from a function:

```
char *foo() {
    char bar[4] = "Bar";

    return bar; // This won't work. Don't do this!
}
```

Do you see the problem here? Basically, as soon as we try to return `bar`, it will be turned into a pointer to the first element in the array. However, as soon as `foo()` returns, the `bar` array will fall out of scope and be deallocated. The caller now has a pointer to garbage memory. This is particularly insidious since things *might still seem to work*; the memory formerly occupied by the array will continue to contain whatever values the array had until something else decides to overwrite that memory, and there's no guarantee whether this will happen sooner or later. This indeterminacy results in *undefined behavior*, which can be a source of very subtle and difficult-to-track-down bugs.

So, in summary: passing an array gets you the same value whether you include an ampersand (`&`) or not, simply because of the way arrays work. You can, and probably should, pass an array around as if it were a pointer, without the ampersand. However, you should nevertheless always be aware of whether you're dealing with a pointer or an array, in order to avoid causing undefined behavior.

> This works, but I was just wondering:
>
> 1. When I use an unsigned char buffer[512], as I did in this case, it works, but when I try it with a char buffer[512], it breaks due to segmentation fault, and so I was just wondering what' the difference between a char and an unsigned char array in terms of memory?

Changing from `char` to `unsigned char` shouldn't cause a crash. What line does it crash on?

> 2. I'm a little confused conceptually about why this would work, because I've always thought that arrays have a fixed size and yet in this case:
>
>    char filename[8];
>      sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
>      img = fopen(filename, "a");
>      count++;

This array does have a fixed size. Your sprintf statement generates a string with the following in it: three digits, a period, and then the characters "jpg". That's seven characters, and adding the null terminator required by C strings makes eight.

Be *very* careful when doing things like this. If you accidentally try to write a string that's larger than the size of your array, C won't stop you, and then you'll overwrite whatever happens to come after the array in memory. This leads to undefined behavior, which means that there's no guarantee of what will happen. Your program may crash. You may silently corrupt some data somewhere else in your program. A wormhole may open to the fifth dimension, causing Earth to get invaded by evil man-eating space trilobytes. Pretty much anything goes, so be careful when working with buffers.

There's a way for that to happen in this program, actually; if `count` becomes `1000` or larger, `sprintf` will give it more than three digits, even though you only asked for three. This will cause the buffer to overflow. In a production app, you'd want to either 1) add a check to make sure `count` never gets larger than `999`, 2) check the value of `count` to determine the appropriate size for the string, instead of hard-coding it to 8, or 3) hard-code the size of the string to be able to hold the number of digits in the largest value that an `int` can store (on Intel x86, that's `2147483647`, which is ten digits, so adding one for the dot, three for the extension, and one more for the terminator, you'd make the string 15 bytes long).

### Edit

My original, hastily written answer to this question was misunderstood by some, so now that I have a bit more time, I'm rewriting it to be as clear and as detailed as I can make it. If you're still not convinced, please read [section 6 of the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: `"&buffer, of course, explicitly tells the compiler to give you a pointer to the chunk of memory, and therefore it's the same as buffer"` -- Huh?? That is not right. (an array passed as a parameter is converted to a pointer to the first element)

Comment: That is because the address of an array is a pointer to the first element, but that does not make it the proper application or use of the pointer. If `buffer` were dynamically allocated, it would no longer be true. Proper use is to simply pass `buffer` not `&buffer`.

Comment: That isn't a dynamic array, that is a VLA, Try `int *f = malloc (5 * sizeof *f); f[0] = 1, f[1] = 2; f[2] = 3; f[3] = 4; f[4] = 5;` and let me know how it works out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you're referring to a chunk of memory allocated using `malloc`, you are correct that `&buffer` wouldn't work. But then it's not an array; it's a pointer, which follows different rules. A C array degrades to a pointer, but conceptually is not the same as a pointer (I've been corrected on this in the past myself). I agree that `buffer` is better to use than `&buffer`, but he was asking why both work.

Comment: That was the point. That regardless whether you have an array or pointer to int, `buffer` is the correct syntax. You don't want to create separate cases for "If it's an array, do this...", "If it is dynamically allocated, do that...", one works for all.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Again I agree, but I was explaining why you get the same behavior with the two when using an array. I wasn't really making a usage recommendation there, but I've edited it now to add one and clear up any confusion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You can also break it by explicitly making a pointer to the array and then taking the address of that; `char foo[512]; char *bar = foo; printf("%p %p\n", bar, &bar); // this won't work.` It's because the behavior is different for an array versus a pointer.

Comment: Thank you - this clarified so much for me!! I guess for the last question I just wanted to know what this part of the code did:

            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", filecount);
            picture = fopen(filename, "w");

because arrays have fixed sizes but it seemed like this was fopen-ing an array to be written to? I'm definitely understanding this wrongly and so I'm just hoping for clarification haha

Comment: @FangShuo It creates an array, then it gives a pointer to the array to `sprintf`, which fills the array with the string it generates from `filecount`. Then, it passes the filename to `fopen`, which creates a file with that filename and opens it for writing.

Comment: Note that `printf("%p %p\n", foo, &foo);` is undefined behaviour and may do anything. (The argument to `%p` should have type `void *`)

Comment: @M.M 6.9.1.10 in [the C11 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): "Array   expressions   and   function designators as arguments were converted to pointers before the call." Therefore the array should automatically be converted to a pointer before it's passed to `printf`.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka They are not converted to `void *` however. Read the specification of `printf`, it requires `void *` and not any other pointer type

Comment: @M.M On pretty much every architecture you could be using, there's no practical difference between `void *` and any other type of pointer in this context. The only distinction between them is whether or not the compiler knows what the pointer points to; at runtime, they're both just an unsigned integer of whatever width the CPU uses for its pointer size. This is needlessly pedantic for something which is for demonstration purposes only and would not go into production code.

Comment: (Aside: I've tweaked this to move the addendum to the correct chronological position, and I've removed the meta/voting commentary, which tends to be discouraged in posts. It's worth noting that most Stack Overflow users do not sign in or vote, so this stuff is noise for most readers.)

Answer (score 1):

> When I use an unsigned char buffer[512], as I did in this case, it works, but when I try it with a char buffer[512], it breaks due to segmentation fault, and so I was just wondering what' the difference between a char and an unsigned char array in terms of memory?

None - `unsigned char` is no bigger than `signed char` or just plain `char`:

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 5     An object declared as type **`signed char`** occupies the same amount of storage as a
> ‘‘plain’’ **`char`** object. A ‘‘plain’’ **`int`** object has the natural size suggested by the
> architecture of the execution environment (large enough to contain any value in the range
> **`INT_MIN`** to **`INT_MAX`** as defined in the header **`<limits.h>`**).
>
> 6     For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
> integer type (designated with the keyword **`unsigned`**) that uses the same amount of
> storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements. The type
> **`_Bool`** and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer
> types are the *standard unsigned integer types*. The unsigned integer types that
> correspond to the extended signed integer types are the *extended unsigned integer types*.
> The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called *unsigned integer
> types*.
> <sup>40)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>40) Therefore, any statement in this Standard about unsigned integer types also applies to the extended
> unsigned integer types.</sup>

*<sup>[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)</sup>*

Just briefly looking at the code, I don't see any *obvious* reason why it should crash when `buffer` is signed vs. unsigned, but there could be something I'm missing.

> why does it not matter if its &buffer and not buffer

Sit down and get comfortable, this is going to take a while...

Array expressions are special:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3     Except when it is the operand of the **`sizeof`** operator, the **`_Alignof`** operator, or the
> unary **`&`** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The *expression* `buffer` has type `unsigned char [512]`.  When that expression is *not* the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type `unsigned char *`, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

So, if you wrote

```
fread( buffer, 512, 1, rem ); // do not use & operator here
```

the function `fread` would receive a pointer as its first parameter, not an array object.  Given the declaration

```
unsigned char buffer[512];
```

all of the following are true:

```
Expression    Type                    "Decays" to        Value
----------    ----                    -----------        -----
    buffer    unsigned char [512]     unsigned char *    Address of first element
   &buffer    unsigned char (*)[512]  n/a                Address of array
   *buffer    unsigned char           n/a                Value of first element
 buffer[i]    unsigned char           n/a                Value of i'th element
```

The *expressions* `buffer` and `&buffer` both evaluate to the address of the first element of the array, but the *types* of the expressions are different - `unsigned char *` vs. `unsigned char (*)[512]`.  A pointer to `unsigned char` will be treated differently than a pointer to an *array* of `unsigned char` in some circumstances.  For functions like `fread`, they expect a pointer to an individual element, not a pointer to an array.

At this point you're asking, "*why* is this the case?"

C was derived from an ealier language called B.  In B, the result of a declaration like

```
auto vec[10];
```

would look like this:

```
     +---+      +---+
vec: |   | ---> |   | vec[0] 
     +---+      +---+
                |   | vec[1]
                +---+
                 ...
                +---+
                |   | vec[9]
                +---+
```

B would set aside an extra memory cell to act as a (kind-of-sort-of) pointer to the first element of the array.  In B, the array subscript operation `a[i]` was defined as `*(a + i)` - that is, given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* from that address and dereference the result.

When Ritchie was designing C, he wanted to keep B's array semantics, but he didn't want to have to keep a separate pointer to the first element of the array.  So, he got rid of it - instead, he added a rule that any array expression that was not the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` would be converted to a pointer expression, and that the pointer would evaluate to the address of the first element.  So, when you declare an array in C such as

```
int vec[10];
```

it looks like this:

```
     +---+
vec: |   | vec[0]
     +---+
     |   | vec[1]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     |   | vec[9]
     +---+
```

No separate memory is set aside for a pointer - there is no `vec` object apart from the array elements themselves.  Whenever the compiler sees `vec` in a context that isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it converts it to an expression that's equivalent to `&vec[0]`.  This is why `buffer` and `&buffer` evaluate to the same thing - the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the entire array.

Array subscripting works the same way in C as it did in B - `a[i] == *(a + i)`.  It's just that in this case, the array expression must be converted ("decay") to a pointer expression first.

*This is only true for arrays* - no other aggregate type (such as `struct` or `union` types) is treated this way.  The mechanics of accessing members of a `struct` or `union` are different from accessing elements of an array.

> how does appending to an array work, conceptually

Arrays are fixed in size over their lifetime - "appending" to an array typically means writing to available or unused elements.  For example, take the declaration

```
char buf[100] = "foo";
```

which gives us

```
     +---+
buf: |'f'| buf[0]
     +---+
     |'o'| buf[1]
     +---+
     |'o'| buf[2]
     +---+
     | 0 | buf[3]
     +---+
     | ? | buf[4]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     | ? | buf[99]
     +---+
```

Elements 4 through 99 haven't been written to yet, so we can add to the string:

```
strcat( buf, "bar" );
```

now gives us

```
     +---+
buf: |'f'| buf[0]
     +---+
     |'o'| buf[1]
     +---+
     |'o'| buf[2]
     +---+
     |'b'| buf[3]
     +---+
     |'a'| buf[4]
     +---+
     |'r'| buf[5]
     +---+
     | 0 | buf[6]
     +---+
     | ? | buf[7]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     | ? | buf[99]
     +---+
```

`buf` now contains the sequence `{'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 0}`, leaving 93 elements available.  We can keep doing this until we have a string that's 99 characters long (leaving 1 element for the string terminator).  But the array's *size* is fixed at 100 and cannot be changed.  If we try to store more than 100 characters to `buf`, what will happen is that those extra characters will be stored beyond the array's bounds and overwrite other objects.  Depending on what gets clobbered, you may wind up with bad data, your program may crash, you may branch into a different routine, or your code *may appear to work correctly*.  This is what happens in the snippet where you try to create a file name longer than the buffer sized to hold it.  Whatever was in memory following the buffer wasn't "important", so the code *appeared* to work with no issues.

There is a thing called *variable-length arrays* that was introduced in C99, where an array's size isn't determined until runtime:

```
int n = get_some_value_at_runtime();
int array[n];
```

However, like regular fixed-size arrays, you cannot change a VLA's length over its lifetime.  "Variable-length" simply means that each time you create an instance of the array, it can be a different size.

If you need storage that can physically grow or shrink as necessary, you'll have to use dynamic memory management routines (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `free`).

Answer (score 0):

Using &buffer and buffer are two different things.
**&buffer** gives you the memory address of buffer variable while using **buffer** gives you the value that is pointed by buffer (its value).
for fread you should use only buffer (or &buffer[0]) and not &buffer.

I don't know exactly what you mean by "appending to an array" but I'll try to answer:
Array is a fixed size of memory block that is stored continuously in memory.

1. If you want to append some more data to it without exceed its size there are many ways to do that. One is to simply keep a pointer to the next index of the array (starting from 0) and every time you store more data to it increase the pointer with the amount of bytes written.
2. If your amount of data exceeds the array size you should use a dynamically allocated array and reallocate it as needed.

unsigned char buffer[512] and char buffer[512] are stored exactly the same in the memory. but notice that you use signed char, you store values that overflow.

```
char c = 0xff // Overflow
unsigned char c = 0xff // OK
```

but that has nothing to do with segmentation fault.

The last part of your question is not understood.